# Angular 14 - Variable is updating in function but not in Component this.variable which is used in setinterval (HTML CANVAS)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, frontend

I'm trying to use this.x in setInterval method and updating this.x on mousemove. The value gets changed in function scope and i am able to print and see that but its not getting updated anywhere else be it function, setinterval. How can I resolve this?

```
window.setInterval(() => {
        this.mouseX = this.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5;

        this.mouseY = this.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.5;

        // console.log(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);

        // this.loop();
        if (this.mouseIsDown) {
          this.RADIUS_SCALE += (1.5 - this.RADIUS_SCALE) * 0.02;
        } else {
          this.RADIUS_SCALE -=
            (this.RADIUS_SCALE - this.RADIUS_SCALE_MIN) * 0.02;
        }

        this.RADIUS_SCALE = Math.min(this.RADIUS_SCALE, 1.5);

        this.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)';
        this.context.fillRect(
          0,
          0,
          this.context.canvas.width,
          this.context.canvas.height
        );

        for (let i = 0, len = this.particles.length; i < len; i++) {
          var particle = this.particles[i];

          var lp = { x: particle.position.x, y: particle.position.y };

          // Rotation
          particle.offset.x += particle.speed;
          particle.offset.y += particle.speed;

          // Follow mouse with some lag
          particle.shift.x += (this.mouseX - particle.shift.x) * particle.speed;
          particle.shift.y += (this.mouseY - particle.shift.y) * particle.speed;

          // Apply position
          particle.position.x =
            particle.shift.x +
            Math.cos(i + particle.offset.x) *
              (particle.orbit * this.RADIUS_SCALE);
          particle.position.y =
            particle.shift.y +
            Math.sin(i + particle.offset.y) *
              (particle.orbit * this.RADIUS_SCALE);

          // Limit to screen bounds
          particle.position.x = Math.max(
            Math.min(particle.position.x, this.SCREEN_WIDTH),
            0
          );
          particle.position.y = Math.max(
            Math.min(particle.position.y, this.SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            0
          );

          particle.size += (particle.targetSize - particle.size) * 0.05;

          if (Math.round(particle.size) == Math.round(particle.targetSize)) {
            particle.targetSize = 1 + Math.random() * 7;
          }

          this.context.beginPath();
          this.context.fillStyle = particle.fillColor;
          this.context.strokeStyle = particle.fillColor;
          this.context.lineWidth = particle.size;
          this.context.moveTo(lp.x, lp.y);
          this.context.lineTo(particle.position.x, particle.position.y);
          this.context.stroke();
          this.context.arc(
            particle.position.x,
            particle.position.y,
            particle.size / 2,
            0,
            Math.PI * 2,
            true
          );
          this.context.fill();
        }
      }, 1000 / 60);

@HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
  documentMouseMoveHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('mousemove', this.SCREEN_WIDTH, this.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    this.mouseX =
      event['clientX'] - (window.innerWidth - this.SCREEN_WIDTH) * 0.5;
    this.mouseY =
      event['clientY'] - (window.innerHeight - this.SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 0.5;
  }
```

I've tried to use DetectChanges from angular but still the variable value after updation is not updated in ts file. Although When I tried to show in on HTML the value was changing properly. But inside a function or internval it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from the interval:

```
window.setInterval(() => {
        this.mouseX = this.SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5;
        this.mouseY = this.SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.5;
...
}
```

They are overwriting the assignment you make in the mousemove listener.